# Reading from file with fast-csv and writing into an array

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm using [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv)'s `fromPath()` method to read data from a file. I would like to write this data into an array (which I will subsequently sort). I would expect the code below to work for this purpose, but it does not:

```
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var dataArr = [];
csv.fromPath("datas.csv", {headers: true})
.on("data", data => {
  console.log(data);
  // > { num: '4319', year: '1997', month: '4', day: '20', ...
  dataArr.push(data);
});
console.log(dataArr);
// > []
```

I am able to read the data in the file with this code, but the array is not populated.

What is a good way to accomplish this, and why does the code above not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *"on data"* callback is asynchronous, and the commands that follow the callback will run before the callback finishes. This is why the code does not work, and this reasoning has been pointed out by others who have posted answers and comments.

As for a good way to accomplish the task, I have found that using the *"on end"* callback is a good fit; since the intention here is to "do something" with the whole data, after the file has been read completely.

```
var dataArr = [];
csv.fromPath("datas.csv", {headers: true})
.on("data", data => {
  dataArr.push(data);
})
.on("end", () => {
  console.log(dataArr.length);
  // > 4187
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Well, I know that this question has been asked a long back but just now I got to work with CSV file for creating API with node js. Being a typical programmer I googled "Reading from a file with fast-csv and writing into an array" well something like this but till date, there isn't any proper response for the question hence I decided to answer this.

Well on is async function and hence execution will be paused in main flow and will be resumed only after nonasync function gets executed.

```
var queryParameter = ()=> new Promise( resolve =>{
   let returnLit = []
   csv.fromPath("<fileName>", {headers : true})
      .on('data',(data)=>{
          returnLit.push(data[<header name>].trim())
      })
      .on('end',()=>{
          resolve(returnLit)
      })
})
var mainList = [];
queryParameter().then((res)=>mainList = res)
```

If you want to validate something pass argument into `queryParameter()` and uses the argument in validate method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer :-)

Comment: this helps, for me my script was not waiting after converting to promise it worked.

Answer (score 7):

As of "fast-csv": "^4.1.3" the approach by @ChandraKumar no longer works

The fromPath function has been removed in place of "parseFile"

```
var queryParameter = ()=> new Promise( resolve =>{
   let returnLit = []
   csv.parseFile("<fileName>", {headers : true})
      .on('data',(data)=>{
          returnLit.push(data[<header name>].trim())
      })
      .on('end',()=>{
          resolve(returnLit)
      })
})
var mainList = [];
queryParameter().then((res)=>mainList = res)
```

Answer (score 3):

The "on data" callback of the module is asynchronous. Therefore, this line

```
console.log(dataArr);
```

will always return empty because it runs before the callback.

To fix this you need to process the array and sort it within the callback. For example:

```
var dataArr = [];
csv.fromPath("datas.csv", {headers: true})
   .on("data", data => {
      dataArr.push(data);

      var sorted = _.sortBy(dataArr, 'propertyX');
      // do something with 'sorted'
});
```